# DataTable takes too much time to draw the table

Tags: jquery, performance, datatables-1.10

Am implemented client-side J Query Data table in my application. I first Initialize the Data tables and via AJAX call am adding the Row . Recursive AJAX call has been made till it fetches all data from the DB. Response of each AJAX call has been added to the Data table via rows.add() api. I don't need server side functionality.At last nearly 4000 to 5000 records(Rows) will be created. But dataTable Takes nearly a minute to draw the Table.

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $('#interactionsHeaderTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'tir',
        stateSave:true,
        info: false,
        deferRender: true,
        scrollY: $(window).height() / 1.5,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        orderClasses:false,
        scroller:{
            loadingIndicator : true
        },
        language: {
            "emptyTable": "No More Interaction",
            "loadingRecords":"Please wait interaction is Loading",
            "zeroRecords": "No interaction to display"
        },
        columns: [
            {"data": "input"},
            {"data": "symbol"},
            {"data": "accountId"},
            {"data": "accountName"},
            {"data": "recievedBy"},
            {"data": "status"},
            {"data": "recievedPst"},
            {"data": "completedPst"},
            {"data": "TTA"},
            {"data": "duration"},
            {"data": "TTC"},
            {"data": "acw"}
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {className: "chkb", orderable: false, targets: 0},
            {targets: 1, orderable: false},
            {className: "acc_wd", targets: 2},
            {className: "domain_wd", targets: 3},
            {className: "aglogin_wd", targets: 4},
            {className: "dateadd_wd", targets: 6},
            {className: "datecom_wd", targets: 7},
            {className: "anstime_wd", targets: 8},
            {className: "timespt_wd", targets: 9},
            {className: "compTime_wd", targets: 10},
            {className: "acwTime_wd", targets: 11}
        ],
        "createdRow": function (td, cellData, rowData, row) {
            var interactionId = cellData.interactionId;
            $(td).attr('id', "trid_" + interactionId);
            row[2].id = "accNo_" + interactionId;
            row[3].id = "domain_" + interactionId;
            row[4].id = "agent_" + interactionId;
            row[5].id = "status_" + interactionId;
            row[6].id = "dateA_" + interactionId;
            row[7].id = "date_" + interactionId;
            row[8].id = "ansT_" + interactionId;
            row[9].id = "timeS_" + interactionId;
            row[10].id = "compT_" + interactionId;
            row[11].id = "acwT_" + interactionId;
        },

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't recommend data tables for returning that volume of data,

try looking at this

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8789/tips-for-using-datatables-with-very-large-data-sets

Comment: That link recommends the server side implementation but in my case it's only 3k to 4k records , But according to docs -->  Each has its own advantages and disadvantages, but the key indicator for which mode you should select is based on the number of rows in your table. As a rule of thumb, if you are working with less than 10,000 rows use client-side processing, for greater than 100,000 rows use server-side processing. In-between is a grey area where you will need to make a decision based upon the nature of your app and the data you wish to display!